# How to provide NbDateService from nebular? NullInjectorError with NbDateService

Tags: angular, provider, nebular

I'm building a custom calendar, and I `extend` from `NbCalendarDayCellComponent<Date>`.
I need to inject other services to my customCellComponent but if I do that, I need to inject `NbDateService` and I receive the following error:

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NbDateService -> NbDateService -> NbDateService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for NbDateService

I tried adding different modules and didn't work.

[Calendar Kit Module](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/calendar-kit/overview#nbcalendarkitmodule)

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.module.ts` add:

```
// ...
import { NbDatepickerModule } from '@nebular/theme';
// ...
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
        NbDatepickerModule,
  ],
  //...
})
```

Then on your `CustomCellDayComponent` it will work this:

```
export class CustomCellDayComponent extends NbCalendarDayCellComponent<Date> 
                                    implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
constructor(public nbDateService: NbDateService<Date>,){
    super(nbDateService);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add a provider `NbDateService` in App.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxGenericTableModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NbDateService  // Add provider in your app.module
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: That will result on a `Type 'typeof NbDateService' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'typeof NbDateService' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.` because is an abstract constructor.